# Show that the pdf of $Z=\ln(y)$

Tags: statistics

[image]

My attempt,

$$z=\ln y$$

$$y=e^z$$

$$\frac{dy}{dz}=e^z$$

I don't know how to proceed. can anyone give me some hints? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the pdf of Z is the derivative of $Pr(Z < x)$.
Thus 
\begin{equation}
Pr(Z < x) = Pr(ln(Y) < x) = Pr( Y < e^x) = \int_{1}^{e^x} \theta/y^{\theta+1} dy = 1 - \exp(-\theta x)
\end{equation}
Therefore,
$f_z(x) = \theta \exp(-\theta x).$

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of $Z$ is given by

$g(z)=f(e^z)e^z$.

Can you proceed ?